# Passing variables to Apollo GraphQL callbacks from useMutation hook

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using the mutate function from the Apollo useMutation hook in a loop in my application.  It's working great, but I need to pass variables that are not used in the actual GraphQL call from the scope of the loop to the onCompleted callback, and I'm not seeing any strategies in the docs or forums.

**Here's the current structure:**

Mutation and callback

```
  const [getBalance] = useMutation(BALANCE_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted: ({ data }) => {
      // I would like to do something with data and the original orderLine here
    },
  });
```

Loop and invocation:

```
  orderLines.forEach((orderLine, i) => {
    getBalance({
      variables: {
        input: {
          orderNumber: orderLines.orderNumber,
          currency: orderLines.currency,
        },
      },
    });
  });
```

Has anyone done this or know the recommended strategy?

Comment: `update` option has access to cache (you can read prev value) ... using loop doesn't look it's a good API ... [and data flow?]

Comment: I don't understand your comment, could you clarify your sentence for me?